# How to make Text A in container contained in container width that can be raised by Text B?

Tags: css

My Situation is as follows:

I have a container with a heading, a paragraph and a button. Texts are coming from the back-end. They get rendered in a Box with certain width (lets say 260px). Now I want the container to get more wider when the heading gets longer, but I don't want that to happen on the paragraph. The paragraph must be 100% width but it can wrap. The header and button cannot.

I've created a JSFiddle for you as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/swxmvgjr/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>heading</h2>
  <p>Nullam vel sem. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
  <button>Link</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>heading that is a bit longer</h2>
  <p>Nullam vel sem. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
  <button>Link</button>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
    .container {
  width: 260px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

  h2 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 250%;
  }

  p {

  }

  button {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/4ojc5fte/

seems someone already found a solution for me :)

```
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-width:260px;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
}

.child div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 0;
}
```